# Understanding the negated character class

Tags: regex, regex-negation

The regex:

```
/''+[^f]/g
```

when applied to the string:

```
don't '''theater'''  but not'''d and not do'''f
```

also matches the three apostrophes in `do'''f`.  Why is the `[^f]` not excluding it?

PS: I want to find consecutive two or more apostrophes followed by not an f.

Comment: It matches *two apostrophes* and one character which is not `f` (the third apostrophe)…

Comment: The `'` matches the first apostrophe, and `'+` matches the second one, and `[^f]` matches the third one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` makes the regex engine backtrack once a `f` is found after 2 or more `'`s. You may prevent with a `'` alternative in a negative lookahead (so as not to consume the character other than `f` and `'`, when you use `[^f]`, the character becomes part of the match since a negated character class is a *consuming* pattern and lookaheads are zero-width assertions).

```
''+(?!['f])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPFPKK/2). Here, `(?!['f])` will prevent a match if 2 or more `'` symbols are followed with `f` or `'`. Also, you may write it with a limiting quantifier `{2,}` (2 or more occurrences): `'{2,}(?!['f])`.

If your regex engine supports *possessive quantifiers* that prevent backtracking into the quantified patterns, use one:

```
''++(?!f)
  ^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/iEaadF/2/) (another way of writing it is `'{2,}+(?!f)`).

If you are using a .NET regex library that does not support possessive quantifiers, you may use the atomic group instead (that works the same way as possessive quantifier, but for the entire group):

```
(?>'{2,})(?!f)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3e%27%7b2%2c%7d%29%28%3f!f%29&i=don%27t+%27%27%27theater%27%27%27++but+not%27%27%27d+and+not+do%27%27%27f).

Answer (score 1):

Because the apostrophe is a character that's not an ***`f`***.

The sample regex matches "At least 2 apostrophes followed by a character that's **not an `f`**".
[image: see]
You see, the last match really didn't include that `f` but the apostrophe. So if you want to exclude the last match, you might prefer this regex

```
''+[^'f]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) so regex won't backtrack to an apostrophe, which is not an 'f':

```
/(?>''+)[^f]/
```

You can play with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/R34usX/1).

If your engine supports [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), then you can use them too:

```
/''++[^f]/
```

If you want to accept any character that's neither an apostrophe, nor an f, then you can define exclude just another character:

```
/''+[^'f]/
```